# How can I retrieve a previous UserState from cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am developing a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework SDK, and I need to pull an old user state from the database for a new user. Users will be called by the bot, and when they are called, their information will be stored in cosmos DB. When they call back that info needs to be pulled. I was thinking of querying by phone number; but how can I restore the UserState to have all the properties as it had when the initial outbound call is made?

This is how the outbound data is stored:

```
DialoutEvent evt;
            try {
                evt = turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<DialoutEvent>();
            } catch (Exception) {
                // not a dialout event
                return false;
            }
            
            if(evt.dialoutMetadata == null){
                // not a dialout event
                return false;
            }

            // create GHL client with endpoints to set and get keys
            GHLClient ghl = await GHLClient.InitializeFromDB(http, evt.dialoutMetadata.location_id, 
                    config.GetValue<string>("GHLAccessEndpt"), config.GetValue<string>("GHLRefreshEndpt"),
                    cancellationToken);
            if(ghl == null){
                await UnauthorizedDisconnect(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                return false;
            }

            // store contact details and GHL integration
            var contactAccessor = userState.CreateProperty<ContactDetails>("contactDetails");
            var confStateAccessor = userState.CreateProperty<ConfirmationStates>("detectionState");
            var ghlUser = userState.CreateProperty<GHLClient>("ghl");

            DateTime apptDT = ConvertToDateTime(evt.dialoutMetadata.appt_date, evt.dialoutMetadata.appt_time);

            ContactDetails contactDetails = new(){
                first_name = evt.dialoutMetadata.first_name,
                last_name = evt.dialoutMetadata.last_name,
                phone = evt.callee,
                contact_id = evt.dialoutMetadata.contact_id,
                address = evt.dialoutMetadata.address,
                request_type = evt.dialoutMetadata.request_type.Trim().ToLower(),
                apptDT = apptDT,
                appt_date = evt.dialoutMetadata.appt_date,
                appt_time = evt.dialoutMetadata.appt_time,
                calendar_id = evt.dialoutMetadata.calendar_id,
                timezone = evt.dialoutMetadata.utc_offset
            };
            await ghlUser.SetAsync(turnContext, ghl, cancellationToken);
            await confStateAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, new ConfirmationStates(), cancellationToken);
            await contactAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, contactDetails, cancellationToken);
            await userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, true, cancellationToken);
```

I was thinking of creating an Azure Function to handle the database access, but what would be the best way to go about it?